# Problem during run an app in a real device

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I don't know why my Visual Studio 2019 is having this behaviour:

When I start it, my device list to run doesn't appear, just shows "Android Emulator", and if I click on it, goes to Android Device Manager page, instead of, at least, show my virtual device or my real device in this button, on dropdown.

But, when I access Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings, and change my JDK path, the devices appears as it needed to shown (seems that it do a refresh on the devices button). So, if in my JDK path is `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311"` I change to `C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot` and vice-versa to appear the devices. Everyday.

What I tried:

- Enabled USB debugging (I don't think that it is the problem, since a virtual device doesn't appear);
- Tried to install another JDK version;
- myProject.Android -> Right click -> Application, and then change "Compile using Android version:". I'm actually using Android 9.0 (Pie), tried 8.1, 10.0, 11.0;

My environment variables are:

For my user:

- JAVA_HOME: `C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot`
- Path Java: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\bin`
- Path: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` `C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin`
  `;%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
  `C:\myfolder\PHP`
  `C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\npm`
  `%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools`

For system:

- JAVA_HOME: `C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot`
- Path: `C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\bin`

I already tried to change my environment variables, inverting when it is jdk of eclipse to java jdk and vice-versa. Even delete my java jdk and use only the eclipse jdk.

None of that steps solve the problem.
It's kind of stressful everytime enter and change the jdk folder to I get run my project in my real device.

Any helps?

Comment: Possible cause: conflict between two copies of `adb.exe`. One used by Eclipse, one by VS. Maybe something runs when pc start up? A Test: BEFORE running VS, run Task Manager. Is there an `adb.exe` running? If so, then that is the problem. Delete that `adb.exe`. Then run VS. Does it work correctly now? (May have to wait a minute for the list of emulators to show up the first time.) If no `adb.exe`, or they don't show up, then use Device Manager to Start the desired emulator. Back to VS. Wait another minute. Show up now? Sometimes, doing all this once is sufficient. -Next day, might work ok.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thank you for the answer. I tried both cases that you said: `adb.exe` was not running before I started VS, and for the second suggestion: My problem is connecting with USB devices/real devices. I already entered in Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> Tools and reinstalled everything. When I did it, my real device showed in list, but when I restarted VS, the error came again, just "Android Emulator". Tried too to delete all virtual devices in case that anyone has error. Nothing gave me some solution.

Comment: oh, its a real device. If you unplug its USB cable, then start VS, then plug device into USB, then wait a minute - still not shown?

Comment: Tried too... This bug/error is really weird, I still don't know what to do to solve it.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse currently? If not, then delete both Eclipse and VS. Remove all java-related environment variables (both user and system). Reboot. Install VS. Less extreme is to change all those environment variables to refer to the JDK VS expects. AFAIK, Eclipse will still work with that JDK. And it should remove whatever inconsistency is messing up VS.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve For certain softwares/IDEs I couldn't uninstall them due to use for other projects. The only solution for me was retire VS 2019 and use VS 2022. Not what I wanted to do, but "kind of" settle for it, and also follow the new VS. I will keep this question opened to see if someone has a solution, to help other people.